# Invalid characters in linux password?

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to automate creating linux users using bash

```
# Below password does NOT work
#USER_PASS="Eb*rx>BN?3x3SKd"

# Below password works!
USER_PASS="qwer1234"

# 2: Create sample user and set password
USER="sampleuser"
ssh root@$HOST "useradd -m $USER -s /bin/bash"
ssh root@$HOST "echo $USER:$USER_PASS | chpasswd"
ssh root@$HOST 'cat /etc/passwd'
echo "test ssh login with $USER"
sshpass -p $USER_PASS ssh $USER@$HOST
```

The above works fine when I use the 'qwer1234' password but does not work when I use the other one starting with 'Eb*'.

Are there any rules for linux passwords, characters etc.?

Comment: [List of allowable Linux password characters](//serverfault.com/q/513203)

Comment: I can't answer the explicit question about rules but the first reason the fancy password doesn't work might be the redirection on the remote side when you invoke `ssh root@$HOST "echo $USER:$USER_PASS | chpasswd"`. There's now a file `BN?3x3SKd` there and it's content is `sampleuser:Eb*rx`. It's because of `>`.

Comment: Also I think the remote side gets `Eb*rx>BN?3x3SKd` as unquoted string so `*` and `?` may trigger shell globbing.